# Скрыть часть длинного текста android

Tags: android

Допустим, есть `TextView`, состоящий из 20 строк. Я же хочу, чтобы в `Activity` отображалась только часть (например, 3 строчки), а остальное появлялось в этом же `Activity` при нажатии на текст. Как это можно сделать? Я знаю, что это можно сделать, обрезав текст и обработать нажатие на `TextView`, показав при нажатии текст полностью. А есть ли другие инструменты (может быть, что-то есть уже встроенное)?

Comment: есть сторонние [библиотеки на github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+textview+expand&type=), в самом API Android такого виджета нет.

Comment: в теории elipsize и maxLines будут нормально работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Допустим, есть TextView, состоящий из 20 строк. Я же хочу, чтобы в Activity отображалась только часть (например, 3 строчки), а остальное появлялось в этом же Activity при нажатии на текст. Как это можно сделать? Я знаю, что это можно сделать, обрезав текст и обработать нажатие на TextView, показав при нажатии текст полностью. А есть ли другие инструменты (может быть, что-то есть уже встроенное)?" />
```

**.java**

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
textView.setOnClickListener(v -> textView.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Параметр `maxLines` будет ограничивать TextView кол-ом строчек, в примере их будет максимум 3. Параметр `android:ellipsize="end"` в конце будет ставить `...`,

примерно вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и при нажатии он развернется, учитывая все параметры верстки, вы можете сделать более сложную логику, например разворачивать и скрывать, или раскручивать по 1-2 строчки, увеличивая параметр maxLines. Также этот способ хорошо подойдет для анимации в будущем, так как метод setMaxLine будет вызывать invalidate для View, вам просто нужно будет поиграться с видимостью.

Comment: все хорошо, только совсем не очевидно, что можно развернуть. в библиотеках есть маркер свернуть/развернуть (обычно треугольничек такой)

Comment: Ну это уже реализация, через spannable можно что угодно добавить с текстом, также как и стрелку через compound drawable. В целом на все можно либу найти, но как тогда на вопрос ответить ?)

Comment: @pavlofff android:ellipsize="end" ставит в конце предложения 3 точки, так что можно догадаться, что стоит нажать для того, чтобы развернуть всё. Но в целом да, все зависит от конкретной реализации